# Finite element method for nonlinear differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, finite-element-method, galerkin-methods

I encounter this problem $$\frac{df(u(x))}{dx} = g(x)$$ with $$u(0) = u(1) = 0$$ I first convert it to weak form $f(u(x))v(x)]^1_0 - \int^{1}_0 \frac{dv(x)}{dx}f(u(x))dx =- \int^{1}_0 \frac{dv(x)}{dx}f(u(x))dx = \int^{1}_0v(x)g(x)dx $ by multiplying a test function $v(x)$. Then how should I write it in matrix form? The right hand side does not depend on $u$ explicit.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Set $G(x)=f(0)+\int_0^xg(s)\,ds$, then you just have to solve the inverse function problem $f(u(x))=G(x)$ using Newton and some version of path-following. There is no reason why a first order ODE should satisfy two boundary conditions.

Comment: @LutzL variable is x! Sorry about that.